# Numpy Matrix initialization with ascending numbers for rows

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I try to have a matrix like:

```
M= [[1,1,..,1],
    [2,2,..,2],
    ...
    [40000, 40000, ..,40000]
```

It's what I tried:

```
data = np.mat((40000,8))
print(data.shape)
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
     data[i,:] = i

print(data[:5])
```

The above code prints:

```
(1, 2)
[[0 0]]
```

I know how to fill a matrix with constant values, but I couldn't find a similar question for this case.

Comment: Don't use `matrix` with numpy, it's a bad practice, they are trying to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple array and don't forget that Python starts indexing at 0:

```
data = np.zeros((40000,8))
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
     data[i,:] = i+1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using `numpy`:

```
rows = 10
cols = 3
l = np.arange(1,rows)
np.tile(l,cols).reshape(cols,rows-1).T
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

Comment: I like that one. Plain numpy, very very quick as well.

Comment: Absolutely best solution, fast and pure numpy, and uses the the obvious solution `np.tile`.

Answer (score 1):

Matthieu Brucher's answer will perfectly do for your case. If you are looking at numbers much higher than 4000 and if time is an issue, you might want to get rid of the for-loop and create a list of lists with list comprehension before turning it into a numpy array:

```
a = [[i]*8 for i in range(1,4001)]
m = np.asarray(a)
```

In my case, this solution was ~7 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

To use `numpy` broadcast over `iterations` u can do,

```
import numpy as np

M = np.ones((40000,8), dtype=np.int).T * np.arange(1, 40001)
M = M.T
print(M)
```

This should be `faster` than any above `iterations`.
If that's what u are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
data = np.arange(1, 40001).repeat(8).reshape(-1,8)
```

Though this is pure numpy as well, this is considerably slower than @yatu's solution.